# ajax isnt sending post request to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Javascript doesn't send any post data to php file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                function showComment(){
                  $.ajax({
                    type:"post",
                    url:"process.php",
                    data:"action=showcomment",
                    success:function(data){
                         $("#comment").html(data);
                    }
                  });
                }
                showComment();
$("#button").click(function(){
                      var name = $("#name").val();
                      var message = $("#message").val();
                      var dataString = "name="+name+"&message="+message+"&action=addcomment";
                      $.ajax({
                          type:"post",
                          url:"process.php",
                          data:dataString,
                          success:function(data){
                            showComment();

                          }

                      });

                });
});
```

form:

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           name : <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
           </br>
           message : <input type="text" name="message" id="message" />
           </br>
           <input type="submit" value="Post" name="submit" id="button">
           <div id="info" />
           <ul id="comment"></ul>
    </form>
```

php

```
    $action=$_POST["action"];
if($action=="addcomment"){
    echo "Add comment WORKS!";
}
if($action=="showcomment"){
    echo "default";
}
```

Tried to add such lines as if post addcomment than show some words, just for a test since sql request didn't but php doesn't show any response at all, like there was no post action at all.

ps. I'm really new ajax so if possible show me a solution to solve it.

Comment: That's not Java code, it's JavaScript. They are different languages. And I suspect the whole page gets reloaded when you click that button, so you obviously won't see any change made by the AJAX request.

Comment: `var_dump` the `$_POST` request in process.php and post the output

Comment: @WesFoster lolstring(11) "showcomment"  before and after. it doesn't receive addcomment post =/ ps. in showcomment it says now while testing  "lol" and the add post should say"works"

Comment: It's probably the URL. Change "process.php" to the full URL (including http://). URLs are relative until you make them absolute.

Comment: Woops, just took a harder look at your code. It's your data. Pass an object instead of a string, i.e. `var dataString = { message: message, name: name };`.

Comment: before click function i have this , maybe it causes the problem.
$(document).ready(function(){
                    function showComment(){
                      $.ajax({
                        type:"post",
                        url:"process.php",
                        data:"action=showcomment",
                        success:function(data){
                             $("#comment").html(data);
                        }
                      });
                    }

Answer (score 0):

You're using a submit button so it will be making the form submit and reload which will bypass your ajax, you can change your jQuery to listen for the form submit event instead like this:

```
$("form").on('submit', function(e){

    // Stop form from submitting
    e.preventDefault();

    var name = $("#name").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();
    var dataString = "name="+name+"&message="+message+"&action=addcomment";
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"process.php",
        data:dataString,
        success:function(data){
            showComment();
        }
    });
});
```

Or simply change the button from type="submit" to type="button" or replace it with a  element.

Comment: What do you mean it didn't work at all? Have you checked for errors in your console, checked your network inspector to see if the ajax request is being posted?

Comment: Also this is on the assumption that showComment() actually exists and your process.php is in the right location.

Answer (score 0):

You are using submit button as Dontfeedthecode mentioned. Your form does not have any action so it is self posting. I have added action and id to the html form and a hidden field to pass the action. Now javascript serialize the form and send it to the process.php.

```
    $(function () {
        $("#my-form").on("submit", function (e) {
            $("#action").val("addcomment");
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: this.action,
                    type: this.method,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        showComment();
                    }
                });
            return false;
        });
    });


<form action="process.php" method="POST" id="my-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" id="action"  name="action" value="" />

    name : <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
</br>
message : <input type="text" name="message" id="message" />
</br>
<input type="submit" value="Post" name="submit" id="button">
<div id="info" />
<ul id="comment"></ul>
</form>
```